# Python MySQL Connector inserting, but info is not actually in database

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-connector-python

I am making a login and registration project. The login code looks similar to this where the query is obviously not an insert statement. This is the registration code below to register a user. The front end sends their json to me as a back end and I parse it. I remember this was working yesterday. Now today, I've noticed it's not inserting data into the database, yet I am getting the true response that it inserted. I check the table and nothing is getting inserted.

```
def auth(n):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='dbuser', password='dbpass', host='localhost', port='3306', database='dbname')
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered = True)
    value_list = list()
    for value in n.values():
        value_list.append(value)
    value_string = str(value_list)
    a = value_string.strip("[")
    b = a.strip("]")
    c = b.replace("'", "")
    d = c.split(', ')
    authquery=("INSERT INTO members (id, firstname, lastname, email, password, history) VALUES (id, %s, %s, %s, %s);")
    cursor.execute(authquery, d)
    if cursor.rowcount:
        return "true"
    else:
        return "false"
    cursor.close()
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()
```

Anyone know why it is doing this? I even tried creating a new table and even a new database.

Comment: Your query looks problematic. In the query string `id` is nothing. So I'm not sure how this would be expected to work.

Comment: The rowcount is -1 when there's an error, I believe. So the premise is incorrect.

Comment: @mechanical_meat no the id is said as a primary auto_increment. That's why it looks like that

Comment: If it's autoincrement you can leave it out of the query altogether.